# How do I write only urls to a txt file?

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to find all urls on a website, but I can't seem to write only the links to the txt file. It writes everything...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = ('https://www.snapdeal.com/')
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for links in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(links.get('href'))
  
urls = open(r'/run/user/759001103/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.112,share=corporate%20share/Corporate Share/Systems and Infrastructure/Engineering/jbot tests/multicats.txt', "w")

urls.write(str(soup))
urls.close()
```

The terminal shows:

https://www.snapdeal.com/products/men-apparel-innerwear

https://www.snapdeal.com/products/men-apparel?sort=plrty

https://www.snapdeal.com/products/mens-winter-wear-store?sort=plrty

and more...

However the output on the txt file is 4000+ lines of html

How do I write a urls list to a txt file?

Comment: You append the `urls` list but then you reasign it and use it as a file object and you're dumping the `soup` into the file so you shouldn't expect the `urls` to be in the file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to parse the URLs of each product on that page. You will need to parse the HTML doc and find all product anchors which you are through beautiful soup. (If you want just the products you might have to refine a bit your selector to something like ‘.product-container a’).
Specifically to the problem you are facing you just need to write to the file from within your loop.

```
urls = open(r'/run/user/759001103/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.112,share=corporate%20share/Corporate Share/Systems and Infrastructure/Engineering/jbot tests/multicats.txt', "w")

for anchor in soup.find_all('a'):
    link = anchor.get(‘href’)
    print(link)
    urls.write(str(link) + ‘\n’)

urls.close()
```